# How to refresh page without incrementing the hit counter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to refresh a page on button click but i don't want to increment the hit counter. Basically, that page have a few grids so I only want to refresh those grid data when I click the Refresh Button but I don't want to increase hit counter on refresh.

Comment: Have to tried `Request.UrlReferrer`?

Comment: but it will increase the counter as well

Comment: are you implementing it in WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Using UpdatePanel would be a good option. You can update a control that runs from the server through UpdatePanel.

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo - but PageLoad is fired for UpdatePanel so some extra logic is probably needed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  depends on the hit counter control being used, I was thinking of a 3rd party control that increments when the control itself is loaded

Comment: if the counter is increments at PageLoad event, then UrlReferrer could be another option

Comment: yes counter is on page load,how can use urlreferrrer?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to refresh only those grid data

Comment: never used ajax.will u please help me for this?

Comment: @VimalSingh there are a lot of reference out there, if you are implementing it in WebForms, use UpdatePanel, if it is in MVC, use PartialViews

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it by using either:

- asynchronous calls made from client to server using AJAX
- using something like [signalR](http://signalr.net/) or Websockets. SignalR will take advantage of websockets when available and then fall back to a number of other techniques to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UpdatePanel.

ASP.NET UpdatePanel controls enable you to build rich, client-centric Web applications. By using UpdatePanel controls, you can refresh selected parts of the page instead of refreshing the whole page with a postback. This is referred to as performing a partial-page update. An ASP.NET Web page that contains a ScriptManager control and one or more UpdatePanel controls can automatically participate in partial-page updates, without custom client script.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First create a long-term storage page: counter.xml that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <counter>
      <count>
        <hits>0</hits>
      </count>
    </counter>
```

Then open Global.asax.cs and add the following.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        //1. Create a lock and a DataSet object.
        private static readonly Object lockObj = new object();
        private static DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup

            //2. Read counter.xml into the dataSet any time the  
            //application is started. Here counter.xml is in the Application root.
            dataSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Add the Session_Start handler to the class. Session_Start only runs when a new session is created and not when a page is refreshed.

```
        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //3. Lock the dataSet to prevent synchronization issues.  
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                //4. Increment hits in the dataSet.
                dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = 1 + int.Parse(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());
                //5. Write the new value to the long-term storage, counter.xml
                dataSet.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```